# Can anyone tell me why the code below used waitKey(20) and what does this 0xFF == ord('q') mean?

Tags: opencv3.0

```
if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
```

What does this `cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF` mean?

Comment: The `0xFF` does not belong to the `==` operator, it's for the `&` operator. If you use parentheses, the calculation order would be `(cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF) == ord('q')`.

Comment: ok thanks! i'm new to openCV so thats why asked it.

Comment: @Progman--can you help me out to understand this thing, it'll be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [waitKey()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) function waits the specified amount of milliseconds and then returns the code of the key that was pressed, or -1 if no key was pressed.

To understand the expression better, let's add some parenthesis:

```
if (cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF) == ord('q')
```

The `&` is a [bitwise and operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=msvc-160) which is used here for bit masking to get only the lowest eight bits (because `0xFF` is equal to `1111 1111` in binary). `waitKey()` returns an `int` which usually is a 32 bit or a 64 bit integer, depending on the architecture. So any "excess" bits are "eliminated" by the bitwise and. The `ord()` function *supposedly(!)* returns the ordinal value of it's parameter, i. e. the ASCII code of `'q'` in that example.

In other words: It waits for 20 milliseconds for key presses and checks whether the pressed key is Q.