# What is "if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:"

Tags: python, opencv

```
if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF ==27:
```

Can anybody tell me the working of this this code in python

Comment: & 0xFF removes the high value bits of a value >= 256. 27 is the 8 bit value of a fixed pressed key, maybe the ESC key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any syntax with (key==27) typically means press the esc key on the keyboard pad.

Answer (score 0):

The `waitKey()`  function waits for the specified millisecond and then returns the code for the key pressed or -1 if no key was pressed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356778/14237825

Comment: Should be marked as duplicate